# iOS8: How to clear a UIView from a UIViewController

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, ios8

I'm trying to update my app to use a storyboard with auto-layout. Using a XIB, I have this working fine. My app has a view controller with a subView defined in Interface Builder. I draw in the subView.

That works.

But I cannot clear (or undo/redo). I can see that the UIView methods are invoked, but I must not be doing something I'm supposed to do.

Here are some code snips, and I'd appreciate some help:

VC simply calls the view:

```
- (IBAction)eraseButtonTapped:(id)sender {
     NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
    savedImage.image = drawImage.image;
    [drawingView eraseButtonClicked];
}
```

UIView:

```
- (void)eraseButtonClicked {
    NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
    self.bufferArray = [self.currentArray mutableCopy];
    [self.currentArray removeAllObjects];
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Both functions log..

These are the touch methods:

```
#pragma mark - Touch Methods
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{   
    NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
    self.currentColorPath = [[DrawingPath alloc] init];
    [self.currentColorPath setColor:self.currentColor];
    UITouch *touch= [touches anyObject];


    [self.currentColorPath.path moveToPoint:[touch locationInView:self]];
    [self.currentArray addObject:self.currentColorPath];
    [self.redoStack removeAllObjects];

    lastPoint = [touch locationInView:self];
    lastPoint.y -= 20;

    if ([touch tapCount] == 2) {
        [self alertOKCancelAction];

        return;
    }        
}



-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject]; 
    [self.currentColorPath.path addLineToPoint:[touch locationInView:self]];

    [self setNeedsDisplay];

    CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self];
    currentPoint.y -= 20;

    lastPoint = currentPoint;

}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
    self.currentColorPath = nil;
}
```

The view calls a separate object to handle the drawing.. This is a code snippet (removing non-relevant bits).

```
- (id)init {
    //NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
    if (!(self = [super init] ))
        return nil;

   path = [[UIBezierPath alloc] init];
    _path.lineCapStyle=kCGLineCapRound;
    _path.lineJoinStyle=kCGLineJoinRound;
    [_path setLineWidth:brush];

    return self;
}

- (void)draw {
    NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);

    [self.color setStroke];
    [self.path stroke];

}
```

Comment: I see that you're adding all your paths to the view's `currentArray` property (then emptying it when you "erase"), but you left out the code that actually renders the contents of that array to the screen. Is it in `-[drawRect]`? It might help to post that code as well.

Comment: Oops. I'm adding it now.. It's not a drawRect function, I have a seperate NSObject to handle drawing. It manages brush, path and colors.